# Função para montar query apartir da tabela e adicionar array na função

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando criar uma função onde que preciso enviar para ela um array que vai está com os mesmos dados da sequencia do insert no banco mais não estou tendo ideia de como enviar esse array para dentro da função e montar o insert

exemplo do array:

`['', '0200', '000000000006054178', 'CIMENTO CP II-F 32-POTY 50 KG', '', '', 'S50', '00', '', '', '', '', '', '\n']`

exemplo da função que fiz:

```
def insertReg0200(reg,cod_item,descr_item,cod_barra,cod_ant_item,unid_inv,tipo_item,cod_ncm,ex_ipi,cod_gen,cod_lst,aliq_icms):
sql = "Insert into reg_0200 (REG,COD_ITEM,DESCR_ITEM,COD_BARRA,COD_ANT_ITEM,UNID_INV,TIPO_ITEM,COD_NCM,EX_IPI,COD_GEN, COD_LST, ALIQ_ICMS) VALUES ('"+reg+"','"+cod_item+"','"+descr_item+"','"+cod_barra+"','"+cod_ant_item+"','"+unid_inv+"','"+tipo_item+"','"+cod_ncm+"','"+ex_ipi+"','"+cod_gen+"','"+cod_lst+"','"+aliq_icms+"')"
return sql
```

Para nao fica digitando muita coisa eu queria em vez de colocar campo a campo apenas inserir o array completo nesse insert

ficando +- assim essa funcao no seu uso:
`insertReg0200(aqui o array)`

Consegui agora modificar um pouco mais essa minha funçao deixando ela recebendo o array e esse já fazendo a inserção direto no banco de dados, ficou assim:

```
def insertReg0200(reg0200):
cur.execute("Insert into reg_0200 (REG,COD_ITEM,DESCR_ITEM,COD_BARRA,COD_ANT_ITEM,UNID_INV,TIPO_ITEM,COD_NCM,EX_IPI,COD_GEN, COD_LST, ALIQ_ICMS) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",reg0200[1:13])
```

Mais acredito que pode ser melhorada mais ainda, estou tentando também pegar as colunas da tabela direto e inserindo para montar a query mais ainda não obtive resultado legal para mostrar aqui. se alguém puder ajudar agradeço muito a como otimizar o máximo possível esse meu insert.

Comment: cuidado com a identação. Em Python ela não é só "para ficar bonitinho".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(eu respondo a sua dúvida, mas as melhores formas de proceder estão ao final)*

Python tem várias - talvez mais de 10 - formas diferentes de formatar strings interpolando com valores. Ficar no exercício "fecha aspas + variável + abre aspas + virgula + fecha aspas + variável") só é algo  er feito em lignuagens sem nenhum desses recursos.

Então, como o miguel citou, o método `format` das strings é uma forma de fazer isso para strings ordinárias.

E como eu citei no meu comentário bem contundente ali, tanto o método format quando tentar interpolar a string com `+` tem o *horror*  de não tomar qualquer cuidado com a sanitização dos dados a serem inseridos no banco. Mesmo que os dado não venham de uma entrada interativa externa - o que abre todas as portas para um ataque de SQL Injection - essa prática não faz qualquer escape dos dados: qualquer valor ali que contiver um simples caractere "'" ou ";"  vai causar um erro na sua aplicação.

Bom - e então? Então que os diversos drivers de SQL do Python tem uma forma deles - separada dos métodos "format" ou `%` das strings para inserirem parâmetros em queries. Esses métodos tem a grande vantagem de automaticamente escaparem da forma apropriada caractéteres que permitem "pular fora" do comando SQL e iniciar outro - além de gerarem queries sintaticamente váidas independente dos dados a inserir.  (Por exemplo, o '\n' que ser quer inserir não gerar problema algum).

VOcê não cita qual é o driver de SQL que está usando (isso é, nem o pacote, nem com qual banco de dados). Há uma pequena diferença por que há algumas formas distintas de se marcar os pontos de inserção de dados, dependendo do driver. Este documento tem a docuemntação dos drivers de SQL para Python, e esta sessão tem os tipos de parâmetros possíveis:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle

ENtão, supondo que seu banco especifico tenha a variável `paramstyle=='qmark'`  (por exemplo: `import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.paramstyle)`  -troque sqlite3 pelo seu módulo de driver) . Isso indica que esse driver vai trocar os caracteres `?` na string de query automaticamente por valores passados numa sequencia de parametros - que será o segundo parâmetro da chamada para `.execute`.

O sgundo exemplo que você deu, portanto, é a forma correta de fazer isso, 
para um driver de banco que tenha `paramstyle== "format"` ou `pyformat`

```
def insertReg0200(reg0200):
    cur.execute("Insert into reg_0200 (REG,COD_ITEM,DESCR_ITEM,COD_BARRA,COD_ANT_ITEM,UNID_INV,TIPO_ITEM,COD_NCM,EX_IPI,COD_GEN, COD_LST, ALIQ_ICMS) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",reg0200[1:13])
```

Não sei o qu e você gostaria de diminuir daí - a hora de inserir no banco dados externos e um ponto crítico da aplicação, e não é bom inventar muita moda - é onde acontecem mais falhas de segurança.

Em particular é importante saber qua dados está indo em qual coluna. 
Agora, se seu aray sempre for coincidir exatamente com todas as colunas, em ordem, da tabela, a Sintaxe SQL mesma permite que você não mande as colunas - basta fazer
 `cur.execute("INSERT INTO reg_0200 VALUES (%s, %s, %s,...)", reg0200[1:13)`

Nesse caso, vamos supor que você não saiba de antemão  o númro d e parâmetros - voce *pode* usar as capacidades do Python de maniulação de strings para gerar o número necessários de `%s,`. 
È importante notar que nesse caso, você usa uma expressao de string para montar o template da query - isso gera uma string que é o rimeiro parâmetro para  `execute` e o sgndo parâmetro é a sequencia de valores em si. Isso garante que o driver de SQL escape cada parâmetro para evitar SQL Injection:

```
parametros = reg0200[1:13]
query = "INSERT INTO reg_0200 VALUES ({})".format(", ".join('%s' for _ in len (parametros))) 
cur.execute(query, parametros)
```

Mas melhor ainda que isso, é, em vez de mandar seus parâmetros como listas, usar dicionários, em que cada dado está associado diretamente ao nome da coluna. Nesse caso, você pode usar a sintaxe do SQL de  `SET col_name=expr, ...` em vez de  `VALUES`. Claro que vai precisar usar a manupulação de daods e strings do Python para montar a query e os parâmetros adequadmente. Os driversd e Python montam os parâmtros com os caracteres de formatação  - mas não o nome das colunas. Esses tem que ser construídos fixos na string.

Então, se você envia um dicionário do tipo `{"REG": xx, "COD_ITEM": yy, "DESCR_ITEM": zz, ...}`  para inserção, você pode usar os métodos `keys`e `values` do dicionário para extrair os nomes das colunas e os dados separadamente:

```
def insere(dict_data):

    query = "INSERT INTO reg0200 SET " + ", ".join("{}=%s".format(key) for key in dict_data.keys())
    cur.execute(query, dict_data.values())
```

**MAIS IMPORTANTE**

mas agora  o melhor mesmo - e esquecer tudo isso, e usar na sua aplicação um pacote de mapeamento objeto relacional, tal como o [SQLALchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/),

Ele garante que você só tem que se preocupar com seus dados dentro do Python, e faz a coisa certa para se comunicar com o banco - e você pode até trocar o banco sem mudar nada no seu programa.

Comment: Jbueno boas dicas, só chamar para um pequeno de sintaxe, esqueceu-se de fechar os parentesis no ultimo execute

Comment: Jbueno estou voltando a programar novamente agora, e estou engatinhando novamente e quero usar o python como minha linguagem principal, como estou usando isso pra processar arquivos textos onde ele tira as informações do layout do SPED ICMS/IPI e joga para um mysql da vida só pra eu poder cruzar as informações, queria um método onde não preciso fica digitando mundos de campos. Muito obrigado mesmo pela dica não só me ajudou mais também me deu um  rumo onde estudar.

Comment: Legal Ricardo - com Python, vai ver que vai precisar digitar os campos uma única vez - mesmo que seja numa estrutura que tenha que juntar mais informação com os nomes,  e ainda assim conseguir fazer inserções de forma segura e fácil de manter.

Comment: (A propósito - o stackoverflow em português tem um outro usuário "@jbueno" que participa bem mais que eu - eu sou o "@jsbueno")

Comment: @jsbueno beleza, fiz essa ultima opção que você passou usando chave e valor e no caso da query o retorno dela deveria ser esse? INSERT INTO reg_c100 SET {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s, {}=%s

Comment: Não - ficou faltando uma chamda ao format ali, dentro da chamaa ao `join`. qrrumei agora- os "{}" tem que ser substituidos pelo nome das colunas, (e ai a chamada a "execute"  substitui os "%s" pelos respectivos valores, já dentro do driver do banco)